# ¿Cómo incluir Bootstrap Carousel en WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, wordpress-theme

Estoy creando un slider para un tema y necesito ayuda sobre cómo incluir correctamente el script de bootstrap en `functions.php`

```
// functions.php    
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-carrousel', get_theme_file_uri('/js/bootstrap/carousel.js'), array('jquery'), null, true);
```

pero me sale este error en la consola:

> TypeError: $ is undefined ---> carousel.js:24:7

También veo que se está cargando `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4`, será la versión incorrecta?

Comment: Ya me dí cuenta de mi error era la forma en cómo escribía 'jquery' debía ser 'Jquery'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pueba con estas lineas de codigo, a mi me funcionan correctamente todos los elementos que proporciona Bootstrap 4

```html
//Aqui añadimos el archivo de estilos de bootstrap
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
      wp_enqueue_style ('bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
});

//Aca Jquery, pooper y bootstrap
function theme_js() {  
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery_js', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'pooper_js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

En la primera añadimos el archivo css de bootstrap, y en la segunda jquery, popper y bootstrap js, obviamente en tu archivo functions.php

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me dí cuenta que estaba escribiendo `jquery` en vez de `Jquery`. Tengo una duda, Pooper es necesario? que hace?

Comment: Para que los dropdowns o combobox se desplieguen correctamente, con el código ese que deje, añades completamente bootstrap 4 a tu wordpress

Comment: +1 por "pooper" XD

Comment: Ah jajaja, no me había percatado que lo escribí mal XD